# How to send graphql query with fragments in Android

Tags: java, android, graphql

I am new to graphql and I need a help to send graphql query with fragments for my android app. 
Below is the query format accepted by network.

```
query{
  user(ident:"JohnDoe"){
    myStory{
      description,
    placements(first:3){
      edges{
        node{
          mediaItemType
          mediaItem {
            ...VideoFragment
            ...PhotoFragment
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }
  }
}
fragment VideoFragment on Video {
    videoHTML
}
fragment PhotoFragment on Photo {
    url(size:10)
}
```

Any help appreciated!!

Comment: how are you converting the query result to a Java Class?

Comment: The result I get is in JSON format and I am using Retrofit library to parse the JSON results.

Comment: so you are not taking advantage of the schema from the GraphQL server, right, but you are using Retrofit model classes, I assume?

Comment: Yes, you are right @mcwise , I used Retrofit model classes as I was not well versed with GraphQL schema at that point of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by adding it in strings.xml as below. make sure there are NO extra spaces.

```
<string name="graphiql_detail_search">
{
  user(ident: "JohnDoe") {
    myStory {
      description
      placements(first: 3) {
        edges {
          node {
            mediaItemType
            mediaItem {
              ...VideoFragment
              ...PhotoFragment
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

fragment VideoFragment on Video {
  videoHTML
}

fragment PhotoFragment on Photo {
  url(size: 10)
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into using this as well? https://github.com/andimarek/graphql-java

Comment: @John Shelley, does graphql-java help to build query and then we have to send it over OkHttp?

Comment: @NguyenMinhBinh its more for server side use, but this project is currently in progress. https://github.com/apollostack/apollo-android
Learn about Apollo and what they are trying to do and get excited for the Android Community or come help us out!

Answer (score 1):

This likely depends on the server implementation of GraphQL. GraphQL does not define the medium, which leaves this question as being somewhat broad. Since [express-graphql](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql) is so common, I'll make a guess that you may be using that. If that's true, you can query it over HTTP with more details outlined on the [documentation for that project](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql#http-usage). If that happens to not be the case, you'll need to do some more digging.

Comment: I got it working by adding it in strings.xml as below. make sure there are NO extra spaces.

Comment: <string name="graphiql_detail_search"> query{
  user(ident:"JohnDoe"){
    myStory{
      description,
    placements(first:3){
      edges{
        node{
          mediaItemType
          mediaItem {
            ...VideoFragment
            ...PhotoFragment
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }
  }
}
fragment VideoFragment on Video {
    videoHTML
}
fragment PhotoFragment on Photo {
    url(size:10)
}